# How to exclude all extensions (but not PHP and JS) from .gitignore sub-folder?

Tags: git, gitignore

I want to exclude in `.gitignore`:

- `admin` folder completely
- `content` folder completely, but only allow `.php` and `.js` extensions in there.

I tried this, but it also allows in admin:

```
**/admin
**/content
!.php
!.js
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try ignoring folders (`afolder/` with trailing slash), but whitelisting folder files (`afolder/*`):

```
admin/
content/*
!content/subfolder/**/*.php
!content/subfolder/**/*.js
```

Adding a dedicated `.gitignore` in `content/` folder is another option, but that way, you can centralize all ignore rules in *one* `.gitignore` file at the root folder of your main repository.

As usual, to check what rule is applied:

```
git check-ignore -v -- a/file
```

Comment: well, i couldn't success. Actually, I want to ignore all subfolders too in `content`, just i want to allow only from `content/subfolder` ...

thanks !!!

Comment: @T.Todua Those rules will ignore all subfolders in content too.

Comment: but, i want to allow only inside one subfolder: `content/subfolder`

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using a different .gitignore for each of those "special" folders?

Comment: in no case i will use that worst solution...  there is excellent answer.  thanks anyway